# open a sqlite database when choosing folder with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an already existing sqlite database in a folder `/sdcard/myfolder/db/mydb.db`.
My app shows a dialog to choose a folder:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

The Dialog pops up and I can choose the folder:

[image]

I choose the folder /sdcard/myfolder/db/ and press choose/ok.

My onActivityResult gets called. I go through all files and if the file is my "mydb.db" then I try to open the sqlite database with SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(); and I get an error (see below)

My guess of the problem:
This will not work, because the openDatabase expects the full path to the db like /sdcard/myfolder/db/mydb.db

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if (requestCode == REQUEST_QUICKLIST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode==42){
                // TreeDialog for choosing the Installdirectory
                Uri treeUri = data.getData();
                DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
                for (DocumentFile file : pickedDir.listFiles()) {
                    if(file.getName().equals("mydb.db")){
                        SQLiteDatabase sqliteTest=  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(file.getUri().getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);   
                    }
                    Log.d("DEBUG FILE", "Found file " + file.getName() + " with size " + file.length() + " " + file.getParentFile().getName());
                }
```

`file.getUri().getPath()` has the value : `/tree/primary:myfolder/db/document/primary:myfolder/db/mydb.db`

How to open the sqlite Database ?

Stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=42, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:myfolder/db flg=0xc3 }} to activity {mycompany.browser/mycompany.browser.browser}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3976)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4019)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1471)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:228)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:861)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
    at mycompany.browser.browser.onActivityResult(browser.java:1533)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6475)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3972)
```

Comment: An Android `DocumentFile` is not a subclass of `java.io.File` or the native filesystem file that represents, however it may (or may not) wrap one.  See if `file.isFile()` returns true.  If it doesn't (if it is using a more indirect sharing mechanism) you may not be able to open it as a database, unless your database engine has been extended to support a `DocumentFile` rather than a literal file system file.  Given that the attempt gets down into the native code (from the SQlite project, not from Android) before failing it looks unlikely to support that.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks. So your answer is : "No this is impossible". I hope not and hope other experts have any hints on this, otherwise this framework is not usable for such case. Can other experts confirm or have another solution ? Of course I know that its not a subclass of java.io.File, but I guess there must be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I am not saying that it is impossible, but rather that it would only be possible if either 1) Your DocumentFile wraps a File or 2) Your database engine has been extended to support DocumentFile references.  The first you can check, while for the second I'm not seeing anything obvious in the Android source code.

Comment: Chris, please please let other experts also give a statement, before it gets to a never ending chat like last time and the question has no attraction anymore. Sorry for this words, but I don't know howto tell. If you have a concret solution, give it here, otherwise I guess It will also be interesting for you to see what others think.

Comment: The problem with "last time" is that you apparently wanted a very different question answered than the one you had actually asked in your post.

Comment: ok , sorry. let it be and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested, due to Lollipop device not available at this time but this should work, let me know if any issues!

```
if(file.getName().equals("mydb.db")){
    Uri uri = file.getUri();
    Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri,
                      DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri));
    String path = ASFUriHelper.getPath(this, docUri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteTest=  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 
                                     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
```

The gist of ASFUriHelper.getPath() method with intermediate methods can be found here: [ASFUriHelper.getPath()](https://gist.github.com/asifmujteba/d89ba9074bc941de1eaa#file-asfurihelper)

Comment: I tested this on 2 different devices with lollipop. Perfect thank you very much !

Comment: This code doesn't work for external SD card. If I pick a folder of external SD card, ASFUriHelper return null.

Comment: This does not work in android 12+

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this answer. The problem for me is that getPath returns NULL on my HTC M8 with SD card when I choose a directory on the SD Card.

That is because the uri does not contain "primary" as espectect in the code of getpath :

```
if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
}
```

for me, type contains "1AF0-170C" and the full uri is :

```
/tree/1AF0-170C:SmartDiveBook/document/1AF0-170C:SmartDiveBook/SmartDiveBook.db
```

Comment: could you please add more source code get better sense of it?