# Write file to directory using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

Using the FileChooser from `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` I want to be able to write a file in the location the user selects. Since the file chooser returns a Tree URI, I use a utility class, specifically the method `FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri`, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36162691/6389372) to convert that URI to a usable android directory URI.

For example:
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0A17-1D03%3ATest`

Converts to this:
`/storage/0A17-1D03/Test`

This is the code I have so far:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose a directory"), FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (data != null) {
                Log.i("URI", FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri(data.getData(), getActivity()));
                dismiss();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I write a file at the location returned by `FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri`? (E.g: `/storage/0A17-1D03/Test`)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach.

Do away with that silly function getFullPathFromTreeUri().

Just create a `DocumentFile` instance for the obtained tree uri.

After that use createFile() on the instance.

Precise examples have been posted before.

Just do a little googling.

Comment: "Just do a little googling" - How do you think I ended up here?

Comment: I have been googling for 4 hours and still don't have a means of creating a folder under the documents tree