# Get all files from external storage (including Downloads folder) on Android 10+

Tags: android, io, mediastore, android-storage, scoped-storage

I'm trying to get all files from external storage. The problem is with the **Downloads** folder. **MediaStore.Downloads** returns only files that were created by my app.

I found this article: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files that in theory should help solve my issue. But I can't get that permission on my Android 10 device. It says *"Activity not found."*

Should I use something else (not **MediaStore** API) to get all files? I need to get names, sizes, and other info so I can't use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29

Comment: `I need to get names, sizes, and other info so I can't use the Storage Access Framework.` Not true. Saf will give you all that.

Comment: @blackapps I'm implementing something like a file manager app. I believe the Storage Access Framework can't return all files. BTW how can I get names and other info using that framework?

Comment: If you wanna make a file manager app then it should contain a File explorer, a SAF explorer, an SMB explorer and a MediaStore explorer at minimum. For the rest: you ask too much.