# How to save a file (image) in Android and support API levels from 21 to 29?

Tags: android, media, android-external-storage, android-storage

All new apps uploaded to Google Play must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher. However, when app targets API level 29, the path returned from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is no longer directly accessible to apps.

Documentation suggests using `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` (not suitable for my use case as the files placed there are internal to the app and are deleted when the app is uninstalled) or `MediaStore`, which is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media).

I got stuck at the following snippet:

```
// Find all image files on the primary external storage device.
// On API <= 28, use VOLUME_EXTERNAL instead.
Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(
            MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
```

As I am trying to support both API <= 28 and API >= 29 I have tried the following:

```
    Uri collection;
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(
            MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    } else {
        collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(
            MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    }
```

However, I am still getting a warning that `MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL` requires API level 29.
Also, following the same documentation, I am trying to set `MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH` to provide the system a hint for where to store the newly-written files. The code snippet follows:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, file.getFilename());
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "My_image_app_folder");

Uri uri = resolver.insert(collection, values);
```

The same problem here, the field requires API level 29.

To sum it up, how to store a file (image) and support API levels from 21 to 29?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you  :

My pictures are storage in my assets folder, I don't know if it's a problem for you.
At the end, the pictures a stored in the folder "Pictures" of android and are recognized by the gallery.

```
AssetManager assetManager = Objects.requireNonNull(requireContext()).getAssets();
    Context myContext = requireContext();
//Essential for creating the external storage directory for the first launch
    myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);

    File photosFolder;
    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        photosFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
    } else {
        photosFolder = new File(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    }
    if (!photosFolder.exists()) {
        photosFolder.mkdir();
    }

try {
        pictures = assetManager.list("photos/dataset1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    if (pictures != null) {
        for (String filename : pictures) {
            InputStream in;
            OutputStream out;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("photos/dataset1/" + filename);
                File outFile = new File(photosFolder, filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(requireContext(), new String[]{outFile.toString()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                        Log.i("External Storage", "uri " + uri);

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Error NPE", "la variable pictures est null");
    }
```