# List all the files in a directory and add a filter for a particular mimetype

Tags: java, android, list, file, directory

I have a program that needs the files existing in a particular folder to be listed, this file array then needs to be filtered for video mimetype extensions only so that they can be populated into a list that when a user taps on that path is parsed and played in the VideoView.

I have tried `dir.list()` but its returning null. The folder whose files am trying to list is the default directory where android places downloads. Here is what i tried:

```
String store = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(store);
File[] mylist=dir.listFiles();
log.d(mylist);
```

I have the permission to read and write to external storage as defined in the manifest.xml file as

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

`log.d(mylist)` is printing `null` while the folder is full of files of all types

Comment: That is not an existing directory. Try `File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

Comment: Still reporting null

Comment: On an Android 10 device?

Comment: yeah its on an adroid 10 device-Samsung A10

Comment: You should read stackoverflow pages now and then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29

Comment: I read the article and the guy said to add something to the manifest file so i did as he said but didnt work

Comment: Why does google make storage more and more hard to access with newer releases?

Comment: So you added something to the manifest. Good. I see. No. I dont see. And if you further only did the things you mentioned here then indeed that is not enough.

Comment: Just before ```public class...``` in the class file i added the code i posted in my answer and lets me use this ```getPublicExternalStorage``` in android 10

Answer (score 0):

I added tis before the main class definition and now i can get to list the files in the ListView thanks to the guy who commented on the post

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
```

Am debugging on android 10 and i guess new releases come with their own restrictions