# How to handle folder starting with dot in folder name in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am facing an issue with hidden folders starting with a dot.
I want to access the WhatsApp .statuses folder but when I add the path it does not give me the files in that folder.

I am using `rn-fetch-blob` package. Below is the code for that:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
    .ls(`${dirs.SDCardDir}/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.statuses`)
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data => ', data);

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

It gives me an empty array.

But

If I rename the folder to statuses and remove the dot then the fetches the images in that folder. Like below:

```
data =>  ["IMG-20201015-WA0003.jpg", "IMG-20201015-WA0002.jpg"]
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

I can provide more details if required.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the same folder starting with a dot but I don't think the dot is the problem but the permission is.

```
 const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir}/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses`;
 console.log('path => ', path);
 RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(path)
 .then(data => {
  console.log('data => ', data);
 })
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> //to test on Android 11.
```

Output:

```
 LOG  Running "TestProject" with {"rootTag":11}
 LOG  path =>  /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses
 LOG  data =>  ["29373787dadf4c5eb21337456a5d949b.mp4", "e44025a00ceb4ef7854145da9621ba49.jpg", "a2f1a25d3a0842b294e36dbe48ad18dd.jpg", "5d0d04c3d369483b9f855e7f3522de6a.jpg", "91fd9117527c4ef88182458dcdc23e70.jpg", "df5c6309de994da9aa54b13a79a71568.jpg", "31570f0c284e401899afcc74aa3ff70d.mp4", "40a31c5dd94c412a816e2a5188ad253e.jpg", "0455956fe743486099d8a8f745e022d1.jpg", "6597bba6de514247af2eb900eb9fbed9.jpg", "3c609d8c5f0a4fdfbff8cef73deff525.jpg", ".nomedia", "f9fcf71ab20c484f9bf92bbae3efcab2.jpg"]
```

Comment: Hi Satheesh, Can you specifically tell me in which file should I write these premissions? I am totally new to React Native.

Comment: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Again please read more about Storage changes to Android 10 and Android 11. The way things work is really different. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934372/android-11-not-showing-whatsapp-status-in-app-storage-emulated-0-whatsapp-medi

Comment: I have added the permissions in the file but it is not giving the date, once I remove the dot it gives an array of all images.

Comment: I also see that it is .statuses in your code and .Statuses in mine. S is the upper case in the actual folder on my device.

Comment: I have tried with both. Even I have created a .test folder, it does not work with that also.

Comment: Once I remove the dot it get all the files in that folder.