# How to access permission allow management of all file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-service, android-support-library

[image]

In Android 10 & 11 SDK 30
How to access all files in android devices and also give permission of Allow management of all files

I have try `requestLegacyExternalStorage`, `defaultToDeviceProtectedStorage`, `reserveLegacyExternalStorage`
and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but not working

[image]

Comment: **Please See** this way in this link , It can be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140033/12272687

Comment: Please See this way in this link , It can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140033/12272687

Answer (score 12):

You can use the below code. It works for me.

```
                        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                            } else { //request for the permission
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //below android 11=======
                            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
```

And add line `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in  menifest file

Answer (score 2):

> MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

That is only for Android 11 API 30.

You have to start an intent for

```
Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
```

To let the user enable all files access.

For Android 10 API 29 devices

```
 requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

will do.

You can read more here: [Accessing external storage in Android API 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29/63842348#63842348)

Answer (score -2):

You are not allowed to. Nobody is. No, you can not circumvent this restriction.

You can only access, edit and delete the apps own data. For more read here. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: I want Access this path /storage/emulated/0/whatsapp/media/.statuses  but in android 10 & 11 is not working

Comment: Its not working because google forbid this.

Comment: With Storage Access Framework user can choose the folder manually and this way it should work. 
That's my understanding. Haven't tried SAF out yet, however.