# How to create a root folder in internal memory in android 10 (android studio)

Tags: android, directory, android-10.0, android-internal-storage

I need to create a folder (can be a file ) in internal storage in android 10. I just need the absolute path of the folder that was created previously so I can write files there. What is the internal storage root directory? Suppose that this is my internal dir:

```
android
awsfolder
booksfolder
```

So this is the root. I need to create a folder here, not in `android->data->com.mycompany.myapp->(not here)`. I have tried following to achieve it:

- config legacy storage supports to true in mainfest
- `getFilesDir()`, `getDir()` : it properly works in android 10 but it creates folder and file in `android->data->com.mycompany.myapp->here`
- `getExternalStorageDirectory()`: it works perfectly in lower android like 7,8 and 9 also creates a folder in root but it is not working in android 10 (getting error no such a file and folder )

I don't need a cache dir using `getCacheDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: `getFilesDir() , getDir() : it properly works in android 10 but it creates folder and file in android->data->com.mycompany.myapp->here` Wrong. That is not the used path. Please find out the real path.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir(String type): it works perfectly in lower android like 7,8 and 9 also creates a folder in root but it is not working in android 10 (getting error no such a file and folder )` No. It does not create a folder in root (whatever you think root is) and it works perfectly fine in Android 10 and 11 too.

Comment: `what is the root directory?` All starts with knowing what the root is. Well find out. Take a decent file manager/explorer. Browse. Investigate and you will know.

Comment: this is not your android root directory its an internal storage directory I know what Is root and how to access it

Comment: i use getDir() and it making folder in android->data->com.mycompany.myapp->here

Comment: sorry I'm using getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the path of  and it not working in android 10

Comment: `use getDir() and it making folder in android->data->com.mycompany.myapp->here` No. Wrong. And you even repeat this error although you were corrected.

Comment: `I'm using getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the path`. Well Tell that path!! And tell what you consider to be root! Also tell full path of all other 'get' functions you mentioned.

Comment: actually, I got the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29/63842348#63842348  one of your answers the reason is I'm not adding permissions to manifest