# How can to add all manage storage access permission in android

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

how to add manage permission after android 11 version. please give me answer step by step.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You already added that permission to manifest.

Comment: but how to get programatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842070/accessing-external-storage-in-android-api-29/63842348#63842348