# Android: Folder Picker ONLY

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-storage

I have an application where when I press on a button it should open the folder picker and allow the user to browse and select a folder ONLY. Then I want to get the folder's path so that I can do some manipulation with it.

I've tried using this code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "*/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, 8778)
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you please help by providing me with some code?

Comment: For those who looking code snippet -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366423/14682570

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> it should open the folder picker and allow the user to browse and select a folder ONLY

The closest thing that Android has to something like that is `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. This allows the user to pick a document tree, which could be a directory on the filesystem, something offered by a cloud storage provider, or other document tree structures.

> Then i want to get the folder's path so that i can do some manipulation with it.

If by "path" you mean "filesystem path", you have two problems:

1. A document tree is not necessarily a directory on the filesystem, and you have no reliable means of getting a filesystem path for one
2. You have no access to arbitrary filesystem locations on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps)

You may want to spend some time learning about [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) in general and [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` in particular](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).