# Xamarin - Downloading file to specific directory picked by the user

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to give the user something akin FilePicker in **Xamarin** that will activate before download method to get specific path to where the file needs to be downloaded to?

Comment: Sure, why not? Doesn't seem like you have researched the topic much. What have you tried so far? Also what platform are you targeting. Xamarin tag covers both Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, macOS, WatchOS and Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I haven't found anything on giving the user something akin FilePicker, but for Folder selection, hence me asking
Anything from using Android-specific methods and classes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898676/simple-android-directory-picker-how#45366423) and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118217/folder-picker-for-android) but everything ends up breaking due to the NULL Point reference error or simply not recognizing elements 
So if you have any advice for this, please do share it

Comment: keep in mind that iOS/Android users do not access to the entire file system like you do on a desktop pc