# How to save Images and Videos in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am creating an app that will save images and videos in a separate folder. If folder exists it will save in that if not exist, then it will create one and save the images & videos.
It can be done in android 10 and below, but I cannot do so in Android 11.
I am new in development, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Android Directory picker - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898676/simple-android-directory-picker-how)

Comment: It can be done in Android 11 too. You did not even try i think.

Comment: File apis doesnt work on new android versions, use saf document apis like aunching a pck folder intent then get the uri from onactivityresult, create a DocumentFile , create outputstream and write to it